# On pushing a path/route to history is throwing error in React.Js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, html

Im trying to create a login page in React JS using Redux, after getting a successful login response, Im trying to redirect the user to the home page ('/' path), but it throws an error in the action layer:

> doLogin: failure  TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>       at listener (createTransitionManager.js:46)
>       at createTransitionManager.js:65
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object.notifyListeners (createTransitionManager.js:64)
>       at setState (createBrowserHistory.js:78)
>       at createBrowserHistory.js:169
>       at Object.confirmTransitionTo (createTransitionManager.js:36)
>       at Object.push (createBrowserHistory.js:149)
>       at user.js:25

user.js file

```
export const doLogin = (email, password) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
                loginService(email, password)
                .then(res => {
                        console.log('doLogin: success ',res)
                        if(res.error) dispatch(loginFailure(res))
                        else {
                          if(res && res.token) localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res))
                          dispatch(loginSuccess(res))
                          history.push('/')
                        }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                        console.log('doLogin: failure ',error)
                        dispatch(loginFailure(error))
                })
        }
}
```

Comment: So, have you setup your history as explained here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3498

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux and then it's a simple `import { push } from 'react-router-redux'; dispatch(push('/path'));`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/history module?
It is very easy to implement in the React project.

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();
```

Add the above code to your index.js file and pass this as props to all the components.

To pass the history as props:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <App />
</Router>
```

Access the history in all the components as follows:

```
this.props.history.push('/login');
```

Hope it helps you. Cheers!!